# Add Div before table when using datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

> Add Div before table when using datatable

```
$('table').wrap('<div class="scroll_table"></div>');
```

Comment: Why dont you create a div over the table´s div?

You can append whatever you want in it for after calling your datable´s stuff...

Comment: i want to add table with content within new div

Comment: You can call your datable´s data in your innerhtml table´s div (span, p table works as well...)

    <div id="div"  class="scroll_table">
    <div id="table"></div>
    </div>

Comment: please see first datatable work flow

Comment: You're not actually adding a div before the table when you do this, you're enclosing the table in a div.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: i want to create a div and add table within it's div

Comment: What is the question ...?

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that instead of creating a table and enclosing it in a div (which is what your code does), you want to create a div and put a table inside it?

Comment: yes exactly bobRodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dom element can be manipulated  as per the following documentation to wrap divs around a lot of the data tables functionality including the table itself https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom